# Custom validate function to parse std::chrono::milliseconds via Boost program options

Tags: boost, c++-chrono, boost-program-options

I am trying to parse in an option via Boost program options, which contain a time in [s] or [ms]. Currently, the variable is hard-coded as, using literals:

```
std::chrono::milliseconds timeout = 10s;
```

I am happy to define it as this in the config file

```
#time in [s]
timeout = 10
```

However I could not figure out how to do the validate function. This is what tried:

```
struct chrono_ms : public std::chrono::milliseconds {};

void validate(  boost::any& v,
                const std::vector<std::string>& values,
                chrono_ms*,
                int)
{
    // Make sure no previous assignment to 'v' was made.
    validators::check_first_occurrence(v);

    // Extract the first string from 'values'. If there is more than
    // one string, it's an error, and exception will be thrown.
    const std::string& s = validators::get_single_string(values);

    // Convert to std::chrono::milliseconds.
    v = std::chrono::milliseconds(std::stoi(s));
}   // validate() for std::chrono::milliseconds
```

Funnily enough I managed to write a validate function for a std::array, but I am not familiar with std::chrono and could not for the life of me figure out how to do this... any suggestions would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the problem? That code looks ok, it compiles. Include a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aside from the question (which isn't clear), the whole point of `std::chrono` is that you do not HAVE to know about the unit.

Just make the argument a `std::chrono::duration<>`.

### Design issues

First, I suspect the real problem you had was that your `chrono_ms` is not constructible. You need to inherit some constructors, like e.g.

```
using clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;

struct duration : public clock::duration {
    using clock::duration::duration;
};
```

Next up, there are issues deriving from standard library types that weren't design to be derived from. E.g., the type of `5 * chrono_ms(1)` would not be `chrono_ms` but `std::chrono::milliseconds`.

Also issues with implicit conversions (due to inheriting explicit constructors).

For this reason, I'd suggest a simple wrapper instead:

```
using clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;
struct duration {
    clock::duration value;
};
```

This leads you to explicitly write what you mean, and not have surprises.

### Validate

Next up, here's my suggestion for an option parser that takes the unit:

```
template<class charT>
void validate(boost::any& v, const std::vector< std::basic_string<charT> >& xs, duration*, long)
{
    po::validators::check_first_occurrence(v);
    std::basic_string<charT> s(po::validators::get_single_string(xs));

    int magnitude;
    clock::duration factor;

    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
    qi::symbols<char, clock::duration> unit;
    unit.add("s",1s)("ms",1ms)("us",1us)("µs",1us)("m",1min)("h",1h);

    if (parse(s.begin(), s.end(), qi::int_ >> (unit|qi::attr(1s)) >> qi::eoi, magnitude, factor))
        v = duration {magnitude * factor};
    else
        throw po::invalid_option_value(s);
}
```

You do *not* need to put that into the boost or program_options namespace. ADL will find it (that was presumably the whole reason you wanted a "strong" typedef like your `chrono_ms`).

A test program:

**<kbd>[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gKJTYl0b6OJlmyZB)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

namespace po = boost::program_options;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

namespace myns {
    using clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;
    struct duration {
        clock::duration value;

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, duration const& holder) {
            using namespace std::chrono;
            auto ms = duration_cast<milliseconds>(holder.value).count();

            if (ms >= 1000)
                return os << (ms/1000) << "s";
            else
                return os << ms << "ms";
        }
    };

    template<class charT>
    void validate(boost::any& v, const std::vector< std::basic_string<charT> >& xs, duration*, long)
    {
        po::validators::check_first_occurrence(v);
        std::basic_string<charT> s(po::validators::get_single_string(xs));

        int magnitude;
        clock::duration factor;

        namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
        qi::symbols<char, clock::duration> unit;
        unit.add("s",1s)("ms",1ms)("us",1us)("µs",1us)("m",1min)("h",1h);

        if (parse(s.begin(), s.end(), qi::int_ >> unit >> qi::eoi, magnitude, factor))
            v = duration {magnitude * factor};
        else
            throw po::invalid_option_value(s);
    }

}

int main() {
    po::options_description options;
    options.add_options()
        ("duration,d", po::value<myns::duration>(), "duration (e.g. 1s or 10ms)");

    char const* tests[][3] = {
        { "", "-d", "1s" },
        { "", "-d", "2200us" },
        { "", "-d", "10ms" },
        { "", "-d", "5m" },
        { "", "-d", "24h" },
        // 
        { "", "-d", "s" }, // invalid
        { "", "-d", "5" }, // invalid
    };

    for (auto args : tests) try {
        std::copy(args, args +3, std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout << "Test ", " "));
        auto parsed = po::parse_command_line(3, args, options);
        po::variables_map vm;
        po::store(parsed, vm);
        po::notify(vm);

        std::cout << "\tduration=" << vm["duration"].as<myns::duration>() << "\n";
    } catch (std::exception const& e) {
        std::cout << "\t" << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Test  -d 1s     duration=1s
Test  -d 2200us     duration=2ms
Test  -d 10ms   duration=10ms
Test  -d 5m     duration=300s
Test  -d 24h    duration=86400s
Test  -d s  Error 'the argument ('s') for option '--duration' is invalid'
Test  -d 5  Error 'the argument ('5') for option '--duration' is invalid'
```

### BONUS

If you, e.g. wanted to make a certain unit the default, replace `unit` in the parser expression with e.g. `(unit|qi::attr(1s))`:

```
Test  -d 1s     duration=1s
Test  -d 2200us     duration=2ms
Test  -d 10ms   duration=10ms
Test  -d 5m     duration=300s
Test  -d 24h    duration=86400s
Test  -d s  the argument ('s') for option '--duration' is invalid
Test  -d 5  duration=5s
```

Comment: Thanks sehe, that worked like a charm. Learnt a lot from your code but std::chrono is still quite foreign to me, so I'll be reading up on it today. Thanks!