# Parsing std::chrono::duration with boost::program_options

Tags: c++, boost, c++-chrono

I'm trying to parse the command line using `boost::program_options` (`boost` version `1.80.0`, and Apple clang `14.0.0` on `arm64-apple-darwin22.2.0`) in order to read a `std::chrono::duration<int>` object formatted as `12h34m56s`. According to the documentation, one is required to overload the `validate` function as follows in my code below.

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace po = boost::program_options;
using Duration = std::chrono::duration<int>;

inline void validate(boost::any &value, const std::vector<std::string> &values, Duration* target_type) {
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    try {
        po::validators::check_first_occurrence(value);
        auto duration_str = po::validators::get_single_string(values);
        Duration duration = Duration::zero();
        std::string::size_type i = 0;
        while (i < duration_str.size()) {
            std::string::size_type j = i;
            while (j < duration_str.size() && std::isdigit(duration_str[j])) {
                ++j;
            }
            int v = std::stoi(duration_str.substr(i, j - i));
            i = j;
            if (i < duration_str.size() && duration_str[i] == 'h') {
                duration += v * 1h;
                ++i;
            } else if (i < duration_str.size() && duration_str[i] == 'm') {
                duration += v * 1min;
                ++i;
            } else if (i < duration_str.size() && duration_str[i] == 's') {
                duration += v * 1s;
                ++i;
            }
        }
        value = boost::any(duration);
    } catch (...) {
        throw po::invalid_option_value("Invalid duration");
    }
}
```

```
int main(int ac, char *av[])
{
    try
    {
        po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
        desc.add_options()
            ("help,h", "produce a help screen")
            ("duration,d", po::value<Duration>(), "duration in 12h34m56s format")
            ;

        po::variables_map vm;
        po::store(po::parse_command_line(ac, av, desc), vm);
        if (vm.count("help"))
        {
            std::cout << desc;
            return 0;
        }
        if (vm.count("duration"))
        {
            std::cout << "The duration is \""
                 << vm["duration"].as<Duration>().count()
                 << "\"\n";
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, this fails to compile, and the compiler reports that:

```
/opt/homebrew/include/boost/lexical_cast/detail/converter_lexical.hpp:243:13: error: static_assert failed due to requirement 'has_right_shift<std::istream, std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio<1, 1>>, boost::binary_op_detail::dont_care>::value || boost::has_right_shift<std::wistream, std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio<1, 1>>, boost::binary_op_detail::dont_care>::value' "Target type is neither std::istream`able nor std::wistream`able"
            BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG((result_t::value || boost::has_right_shift<std::basic_istream<wchar_t>, T >::value),
            ^                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I've also tried implementing the `istream` `operator>>` as well as overloading `boost::lexical_cast` for the `std::chrono::duration<int>` class but with no success.  What am I missing here?

#### Edit after @rubenvb 's answer

I tried making `std::chrono::duration<int>` both `std::istream` and `std::wistream` able, but again to no avail. Note that `std::chrono::from_stream` is not available on my compiler.

```
template <typename String>
inline Duration parseDuration(const String& duration_str)
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    Duration duration;
    typename String::size_type i = 0;
    while (i < duration_str.size()) {
        std::wstring::size_type j = i;
        while (j < duration_str.size() && std::iswdigit(duration_str[j])) {
            ++j;
        }
        int v = std::stoi(duration_str.substr(i, j - i));
        i = j;
        if (i < duration_str.size() && duration_str[i] == 'h') {
            duration += v * 1h;
            ++i;
        } else if (i < duration_str.size() && duration_str[i] == 'm') {
            duration += v * 1min;
            ++i;
        } else if (i < duration_str.size() && duration_str[i] == 's') {
            duration += v * 1s;
            ++i;
        }
    }
    return duration;
}
```

```
inline std::wistream& operator>>(std::wistream& is, Duration& duration) {
    std::wstring duration_str;
    is >> duration_str;
    duration = parseDuration(duration_str);
    return is;
}

inline std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Duration& duration) {
    std::string duration_str;
    is >> duration_str;
    duration = parseDuration(duration_str);
    return is;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overload `operator>>`. Keep in mind it relies on ADL, though, so it needs to be in `std::chrono` namespace.

However, that's icky, as it will either lead to surprises to other code or even risk ODR violations across TUs.

Instead, notice that `validate` **also** leverages ADL. Finally note that your overload can be in any of the associated namespaces: `std` (due to `vector` and `basic_string`), `std::chrono` (due to `duration) but also` boost`(due to`any`)!This vastly reduces the potential to interfere with current or future standard symbols.

So here's fixed:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f31deaa2f60566e5)**

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

namespace po = boost::program_options;
using Duration = std::chrono::duration<int>;

namespace boost {

    template <class CharT>
    void validate(boost::any& value, std::vector<std::basic_string<CharT>> const& values, Duration*, int) {
        using namespace std::chrono_literals;
        try {
            po::validators::check_first_occurrence(value);
            auto                   duration_str = po::validators::get_single_string(values);
            Duration               duration     = Duration::zero();
            std::string::size_type i            = 0;
            while (i < duration_str.size()) {
                std::string::size_type j = i;
                while (j < duration_str.size() && std::isdigit(duration_str[j])) {
                    ++j;
                }
                int v = std::stoi(duration_str.substr(i, j - i));
                i     = j;
                if (i < duration_str.size() && duration_str[i] == 'h') {
                    duration += v * 1h;
                    ++i;
                } else if (i < duration_str.size() && duration_str[i] == 'm') {
                    duration += v * 1min;
                    ++i;
                } else if (i < duration_str.size() && duration_str[i] == 's') {
                    duration += v * 1s;
                    ++i;
                }
            }
            value = boost::any(duration);
        } catch (...) {
            throw po::invalid_option_value("Invalid duration");
        }
    }

} // namespace boost

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    po::options_description opts("Demo");
    opts.add_options()                                //
        ("duration,d", po::value<Duration>(), "test") //
        ;

    std::cout << opts << "\n";

    po::variables_map vm;
    store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, opts), vm);

    if (vm.contains("duration")) {
        std::cout << "Value: " << vm["duration"].as<Duration>() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints e.g.

```
g++ -std=c++20 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp -lboost_program_options
./a.out -d 3m
Demo:
  -d [ --duration ] arg test

Value: 180s
```

Comment: I didn't review your parsing code. Perhaps use a parser generator to make it easier to verify/maintain. I just noticed this eerily similar answer by a guy you might recognize https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45071699/custom-validate-function-to-parse-stdchronomilliseconds-via-boost-program-op

Comment: Interestingly, while your standalone code runs as expected, I can't seem to run it in the context of my code -- i get exactly the same error when I place `validate()` inside the boost namespace. What did work though was putting the `>>` overloads in the `std::chrono` namespace. I wonder why that is?

Comment: Because you didn't copy my code? I suspect you missed the other (subtle) differences.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the error you're getting is that you don't have an `operator>>` defined for `std::wistream` (i.e. the `std::basic_istream<wchar_t>` in your error message).

Additionally, you can extract a `std::chrono::duration` from a stream using [`from_stream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/from_stream). So that can easily replace your manual parsing code.

Comment: Please see my edit. Tried your suggestion but I get exactly the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better approach is to add a specialization of `lexical_cast` or  `try_lexical_convert` method from [boost conversion library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/conversion.html).

The code in program options [calls](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/boost/program_options/detail/value_semantic.hpp) internally `boost::lexical_cast<>` (from the conversion lib) to convert between text and the desired type, and the cast [uses](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/boost/lexical_cast.hpp) internally `try_lexical_convert`.

This way you don't have to repeat the boilerplate validate code (i.e., things like `check_first_occurrence` and `get_single_string`) every time you need to support yet another type.

Also, if you want to set default value and output `options_description`, then you also have to add conversion from duration to string.

Have a look at an example code that I use to set timeouts in a config file (hence it supports only number followed by us/ms/s units):

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <regex>

namespace boost::conversion::detail {
    template<>
    bool try_lexical_convert<std::chrono::microseconds, std::string>(const std::string& in, std::chrono::microseconds& out){
        std::smatch m;
        if(!std::regex_match(in, m, std::regex(R"((\d+(?:\.\d*)?)\s*([um]?)s)",std::regex_constants::icase)))
            return false;
        
        std::string number = m.str(1);
        std::string unit   = m.str(2);
        
        char * end;
        double count = std::strtod(number.data(), &end);
        if(number.data() + number.length() != end)
            return false;
        
        if     (unit.empty()) count *= 1e6;
        else if(unit == "m" ) count *= 1e3;
        else if(unit != "u" ) assert(false);
        
        out = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(std::chrono::duration<double, std::micro>(count));
        
        return true;
    }

    template<>
    bool try_lexical_convert<std::string, std::chrono::microseconds>(const std::chrono::microseconds& in, std::string& out){
        out = std::to_string(in.count()) + "us";
        return true;
    }
}

#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    using namespace std::literals;
    using namespace boost::program_options;

    std::chrono::microseconds us;

    options_description opts;
    opts.add_options()("time,t", value(&us)->default_value(10ms), "some time");
    std::cout << opts;

    variables_map vm;
    store(parse_command_line(argc, argv, opts), vm);
    notify(vm);

    std::cout << us.count() << "us\n" << us.count()/1e3 << "ms\n" << us.count()/1e6 << "s" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

(this should compile with C++17, and with minor changes it should work with C++11 as well)