# Use a custom class to validate options with boost::program_options

Tags: c++, boost, c++17

My experience with C++ is summarized in a few weeks of learning. I apologize if the question I ask sounds absurd to some experienced people.

I am trying to structure a small project and I have decided to use the [Boost.program_options](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/program_options.html).

I have created a class called `options manager` to manage all the command line operations from it.

This is the content of the `options_manager` class:

`options_manager.h`

```
#include "iostream"
#include "filesystem"
#include "boost/program_options.hpp"

namespace cli {
    class options_manager {
    public:
        options_manager(int argc, char *argv[]);

    private:
        boost::program_options::variables_map variables_map;
        boost::program_options::options_description options_description;
    };
}
```

`options_manager.cpp`

```
#include "options_manager.h"

cli::options_manager::options_manager(int argc, char **argv) {
    options_description.add_options()
            ("help", "")
            ("path", boost::program_options::value<std::filesystem::path>()->required(), "");
    try {
        boost::program_options::store(
                boost::program_options::parse_command_line(argc, argv, options_description), variables_map
        );

        if (argc == 1 || variables_map.count("help")) {
            std::cout << options_description << std::endl;
            std::exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }

        boost::program_options::notify(variables_map);

    } catch (const boost::program_options::error &exception) {
        std::cerr << exception.what() << std::endl;
        std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Since I would like to validate all the option values passed by the user. I would like to use the [Custom Validators](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/program_options/howto.html#id-1.3.30.6.7) provided by `Boost`. But I would like to structure my validations and define each of them in a separate class. For example, for the `path` option, there will be a class that contains its validation named `path_option`.

Since all classes will contain similar methods and the only thing they will contain different so far is their validation logic, I have decided to use class inheritance as follows:

I have created an interface called `option` and all the validation classes will implement this interface. The validation classes should only modify the `passes` method to define the logic of how the value passed by the user will be validated.

So, what I did was:

`option.h`

```
#include "iostream"
#include "boost/program_options.hpp"

namespace cli {
    template<class T>
    class option {
    public:
        option() = default;

        virtual bool passes() = 0;

        virtual void validate(boost::any &value, const std::vector<std::string> &values, T *, int) final;
    };

    template<class T>
    void option<T>::validate(boost::any &value, const std::vector<std::string> &values, T *, int) {
        if (passes()) {
            std::cout << "OK";
        }
    }
}
```

`path_option.h`

```
#include "iostream"
#include "option.h"
#include "filesystem"
#include "boost/program_options.hpp"

namespace cli::options {
    class path_option : public option<std::filesystem::path> {
    public:
        bool passes() override;
    };
}
```

`path_option.cpp`

```
#include "path_option.h"

bool cli::options::path_option::passes() {
    // TODO: Something to validate here...
}
```

Then I modified the `options manager.cpp` file:

```
#include "options_manager.h"
#include "options/path_option.h"

cli::options_manager::options_manager(int argc, char **argv) {
    options_description.add_options()
            ("help", "")
            ("path_option", boost::program_options::value<cli::options::path_option>()->required(), "");

...
```

But, when I try to compile, I receive the next error:

```
/usr/include/boost/lexical_cast/detail/converter_lexical.hpp: In instantiation of ‘struct boost::detail::deduce_target_char_impl<boost::detail::deduce_character_type_later<cli::options::path_option> >’:
/usr/include/boost/lexical_cast/detail/converter_lexical.hpp:270:89:   required from ‘struct boost::detail::deduce_target_char<cli::options::path_option>’
/usr/include/boost/lexical_cast/detail/converter_lexical.hpp:407:92:   required from ‘struct boost::detail::lexical_cast_stream_traits<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, cli::options::path_option>’
/usr/include/boost/lexical_cast/detail/converter_lexical.hpp:468:15:   required from ‘struct boost::detail::lexical_converter_impl<cli::options::path_option, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >’
/usr/include/boost/lexical_cast/try_lexical_convert.hpp:201:44:   required from ‘bool boost::conversion::detail::try_lexical_convert(const Source&, Target&) [with Target = cli::options::path_option; Source = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’
/usr/include/boost/lexical_cast.hpp:41:60:   required from ‘Target boost::lexical_cast(const Source&) [with Target = cli::options::path_option; Source = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’
/usr/include/boost/program_options/detail/value_semantic.hpp:92:36:   required from ‘void boost::program_options::validate(boost::any&, const std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<charT> >&, T*, long int) [with T = cli::options::path_option; charT = char]’
/usr/include/boost/program_options/detail/value_semantic.hpp:184:21:   required from ‘void boost::program_options::typed_value<T, charT>::xparse(boost::any&, const std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<charT> >&) const [with T = cli::options::path_option; charT = char]’
/usr/include/boost/program_options/detail/value_semantic.hpp:174:5:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/lexical_cast/detail/converter_lexical.hpp:243:13: error: static assertion failed: Target type is neither std::istream`able nor std::wistream`able
  243 |             BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG((result_t::value || boost::has_right_shift<std::basic_istream<wchar_t>, T >::value),
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/boost/lexical_cast/detail/converter_lexical.hpp:243:13: note: ‘(((bool)boost::integral_constant<bool, false>::value) || ((bool)boost::integral_constant<bool, false>::value))’ evaluates to false
```

According to the `Boost` documentation, what I need to do to achieve what I'm trying to do is just overload the `validate` method. Unfortunately it hasn't worked.

I would appreciate any help from someone with experience. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> According to the Boost documentation, what I need to do to achieve what I'm trying to do is just overload the validate method.

That's not entirely accurate. In fact it's entirely inaccurate. Since C++ doesn't have methods, let's assume you meant "member function". The documentation doesn't refer to member functions, at all. The reason is that they want you to be able to validate any type, including e.g. your own `enum` types, which could never implement a member function.

The documentation said just "function overload" which was meant to imply a free function, specifically one overloaded via [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).

Instead of shoe-horning the customization point `validate` into an OOP paradigm, just embrace the library's design:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e7110cb2a0ccd96c)**

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>

namespace po = boost::program_options;

namespace boost {
    void validate(boost::any& v, std::vector<std::string> const& values, std::filesystem::path*, int) {
        namespace pov = po::validators;
        std::cerr << "Validating " << pov::get_single_string(values) << "\n";

        pov::check_first_occurrence(v);
        std::filesystem::path p(pov::get_single_string(values));
        if (!p.is_relative())
            throw std::runtime_error("path must be relative");
        if (!is_regular_file(p))
            throw std::runtime_error("path must be an existing regular file");
        v = p;
    }
} // namespace boost

int main(int argc, char** argv) try {
    po::options_description options_description;
    options_description.add_options()("help", "") //
        ("path", po::value<std::filesystem::path>()->required(), "");

    po::variables_map vm_;
    store(                                                   
        parse_command_line(argc, argv, options_description),
        vm_);

    if (argc == 1 || vm_.count("help")) {
        std::cout << options_description << std::endl;
        std::exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    notify(vm_);
} catch (std::exception const& e) {
    std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

With some test cases:

```
g++ -std=c++20 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp -lboost_program_options
touch a.txt
ln -sfv a.txt b.txt
mkdir c/
```

Prints

```
+ ./a.out
  --help 
  --path arg

+ ./a.out --path=a.txt
Validating a.txt
+ ./a.out --path=b.txt
Validating b.txt
+ ./a.out --path=c/
Validating c/
Error: path must be an existing regular file
+ ./a.out --path=/tmp/1703168795-1419417363/a.txt
Validating /tmp/1703168795-1419417363/a.txt
Error: path must be relative
```

## Notes

Note that the overloads must be found via ADL. This explains that we made it in namespace `boost`, see also:

- [Using boost::program_options with std::optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66539770/using-boostprogram-options-with-stdoptional/66548554#66548554)
- [Custom validate function to parse std::chrono::milliseconds via Boost program options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45071699/custom-validate-function-to-parse-stdchronomilliseconds-via-boost-program-op/45075634#45075634)

Regardless of everything, any validation specified in this way is a validation for a TYPE, not an option. So unless your options *all* have *unique types* you will find this approach lacking.

In fairness I think `validate` is a bit of a misnomer: it should have been called "custom option value parser" instead of "custom validator". I think actual validation is best done *AFTER* parsing/storing/notifying. That way, inconsistent combinations of options can be validated, even after e.g. reading additional options from config files.